# How to get patch-level kernel updates

Tags: kernel, updates

For driver compatibility reasons, I had to get rid of `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` and downgrade to a lower kernel. Let's take kernel `5.11.22` as an example. That's the newest patch in the `5.11` line. I used [Mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) to install this kernel and `apt` to remove the generic packages. Now I only have the kernel `5.11.22` installed.

How do I make sure that updates to `5.11.23`, `5.11.24` etc. are installed (semi-) automatically once these patches come out?

Comment: Ubuntu only used the 5.11 kernel with Ubuntu 21.04 (*and for a few months with 20.04 with HWE before moving to the 21.10 kernel*).  There are no patches created for it, as its' *unsupported* by Ubuntu, with the GA & HWE stack (5.4 or 5.15) still receiving automatic security fixes/patches. If you don't want HWE, why not use the GA kernel stack? which does receive security patches automatically.

Comment: I used the newest that worked. How do I install Ubuntu with GA?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and search for "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:*"   The media (ISO) used to install your system dictates the kernel stack used.